# Activating Figure and Table Description in acmart package

Tags: floats, description, acmart

The acmart LaTeX template from https://www.acm.org/publications/taps/word-template-workflow does not seem to show the content of the `\Description` command.

As a reproduction-example, consider the template inside the zip-file that acm provides (https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/consolidated-tex-template/acmart-primary.zip)
and look at the code acmart-master/samples/samples.dtx where its says

```
\begin{teaserfigure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{sampleteaser}
   \caption{Seattle Mariners at Spring Training, 2010.}
   \Description{Enjoying the baseball game from the third-base seats. Ichiro Suzuki preparing to bat.}
   \label{fig:teaser}
\end{teaserfigure}
```

It has a `\caption` and a `\Description` command in it. So I would expect to see both texts in the pdf. Yet, even the precompiled pdfs that come within that zip file do not show that what's in the `\Description` and only show that what's in the `\caption`. You can confirm this by viewing acmart-primary/acmart-master/samples/sample-acmsmall-conf.pdf, for example.

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: The text you place inside of the `\Description` environment is forexample intended to be read aloud by a software used by visually challenged readers of your paper. See also: https://www.acm.org/publications/taps/describing-figures/

Comment: Thanks. I missed that.